# ¿Cómo colocar hora en input?

Tags: javascript, html

Podrían ayudarme con lo siguiente, necesito que la función que muestra la hora y minuto se muestre en el `<input type="text"/>` con `id ="minor2"` y no en un `alert` ¿No se si me explique?

```html
Select some of the text: <input type="text" id="minor2" value="Hello world!"> 
Select some of the text: <input type="text" id="minor2" value="Hello world!" onfocus="myFunction()" onclick="myFunction()"> 
Select some of the text: <input type="text" id="minor3" value="Hello world!">

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("minor").onblur = function() {
      var fecha = new Date();
      alert("Hora: " + fecha.getHours() + "\nMinuto: " + fecha.getMinutes());
    }
    document.getElementById("minor2").value = "Minor";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Reemplaza el contenido del atributo value en el input con lo que le quieras poner. En este caso, la última instrucción no debería poner el texto `Minor` sino el string que estás armando en el alert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que colocar ids únicos, tienes el id `minor2` en los 2 primeros input, luego en la función estas obteniendo el elemento con el id `minor`, el cual no existe, igualmente para lograr lo que necesitas solo es necesaria una función, algo así:

```js
function myFunction() {
      var fecha = new Date();
      var output = "Horas: " + (fecha.getHours()<10 ? '0' : '') +fecha.getHours()+ " Minutos: " + (fecha.getMinutes()<10 ? '0' : '')+fecha.getMinutes();
    document.getElementById("minor2").value = output;
  }
```

```html
Select some of the text: <input type="text" id="minor" value="Hello world!"> 
Select some of the text: <input type="text" id="minor2" value="Hello world!" onfocus="myFunction()" onclick="myFunction()"> 
Select some of the text: <input type="text" id="minor3" value="Hello world!">
```

Ojala sea lo que necesitas. Saludos.

Comment: ¡EXCELENTE!
Muchisimas gracias Josue :D

Comment: @MinorMX Recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada si te funciono. Saludos.

Comment: Oye pero me doy cuenta que cuando son minutos del 00 al 09 solo imprime por ejemplo 11:0, 11:1, 11:2....11::9 ¿Como corrijo eso? creo que hace tiempo habiaa hecho algo asi y se corrigia con una condicional ¿no? Jamas habia usado la funcion de "Date" tanto

Comment: ¡no me deja, como hago eso!

Comment: @MinorMX acabo de editar la respuesta para que añada el 0 en caso que las horas o minutos sean menores a 10, por otro lado para aceptar la respuesta mira aqui https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Saludos.

Comment: @Josue_Arriola ¡Que elegancia la de Francia! Quedo super genial, te debo una viejo, creo que palomee el tick verde ¿Es ese? espero te sirva de algo...

Answer (score 1):

He realizado algunos cambios en tu código, como cambios de `id` en los `input` y asignación, también puse la hora con formato dentro de una variable para que sea utilizable.

```
Select some of the text: <input type="text" id="minor1" value="Hello world!"> 
Select some of the text: <input type="text" id="minor2" value="Hello world!" onfocus="myFunction()" onclick="myFunction()"> 
Select some of the text: <input type="text" id="minor3" value="Hello world!">

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("minor2").onblur = function() {
      var fecha = new Date();
      const fechaConFormato = "Hora: " + fecha.getHours() + "\nMinuto: " + fecha.getMinutes()
      alert(fechaConFormato);
    }
    document.getElementById("minor2").value = fechaConFormato;
  }
</script>
```

AL hacer foco sobre el segundo `input` (minor2) debería mostrar una alerta y posteriormente la fecha dentro del `input`.

Comment: Pues me aparece el "alert" pero no en el "input", ahora ya entendi un poco más del código ¡Gracias Jonathan!

Comment: Comenta el alert para que lo veas mejor.